# Is there a trick to using the air cushions in Cut the Rope?

Tags: cut-the-rope

I can't seem to get the hang of the air cushions in Cut the Rope.  I must average 20 taps for each puff of air.  I find levels that require multiple puffs in quick succession to be an exercise in frustration.  It's usually obvious what I'm supposed to do, but actually getting the cushions to puff at the right moment is a nightmare.

Am I the only one who can't seem to tap the right spot on an air cushion?  Is there a way to make it easier?

Answer (score 1):

Timing is important. Typically you should tap the air cushion just as the candy is moving away from it, and not when it's moving towards the cushion (the latter slows down the candy, which is useful in some situations).

For example, say you have a cushion on the left, pointing right, and a piece of candy on a string in the middle. The first puff will push it away (to the right) slightly. If you immediately tap again and again it makes very little difference. But wait until the candy has swung all the way back to the left, closer to the cushion. Just as it changes direction, tap again and it will swing much further to the right.

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my problem.  I understand the physics.  My major problem is that I tap the air cushion *and it does not puff*.  I can't seem to target the right spot on the cushion.

Comment: @cjm Oh sorry, yes I misunderstood your question. I never had a problem actually tapping the cushions myself so can't really help with that, sorry. I'll leave my answer here for now since it does answer the title question and may be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

try to use your fingers instead of your thumbs. You can try to use two different fingers to tap very quickly (similar to the motion of a drum), or you can hold it with one hand while you tap your finger with the other. EDIT: You could also look into buying an iphone stylus, though that may seem overboard.
[link to apple stylus](https://www.apple.com/accessibility/resources/iphone.html)

Comment: I do use my finger.  I can tap fairly quickly, but I don't seem to hit the right spot. Most of my taps simply do nothing.  I do have fairly large hands.